# How to add sort,limit and skip in the aggregate query shown below?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

This is my data structure

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f37f18517f72bc09ee7632"),
    "name" : "testdata",
    "createdBy" : "57f1fdef1d3c40141617d215",

    "transitionEnabled" : false,
    "status" : "active",
    "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2016-10-04T10:06:16.195Z"),
    "accounts" : [ 
        "57f37f75517f72bc09ee7634"
    ],
    "deliverables" : [],
    "risks" : [],
    "issues" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57f38398517f72bc09ee7680"),
        "title" : "test",
        "description" : "Delay in testing due to issues with Provider Finder dataload in the test region. This has impacted the production release planned for Sep 30th",
        "plannedStartDate" : ISODate("2016-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "plannedEndDate" : ISODate("2016-10-30T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "assignedTo" : "57f375ea517f72bc09ee762a",
        "createdBy" : ObjectId("57f375ea517f72bc09ee762a"),
        "likes" : 0,
        "createdDateTime" : ISODate("2016-10-04T10:25:28.301Z"),
        "status" : "open",
        "stakeholders" : [],
        "__v" : 0,
        "lastUpdatedTime" : ISODate("2019-11-15T09:19:06.279Z")
    },
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I would like to select all the issues group by the organization and I want to implement sort,limit and skip for those data(the sub array issues data only from the above). For that I've tried the following code

`db.organizations.aggregate([ 
    {
        "$lookup" : { 
            "from" : "issues", 
            "localField" : "issues.str",
            "foreignField" : "_id.str", 
            "as" : "issues" 
        }
    },
    {$sort: {weight: -1, "issues.lastUpdatedTime": 1}}
    {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$issues",
         },
     },
])`

I am getting the result as follows.

[image]How to sort and set limit and skip for the below query? Results returned by the query is also attached.

But I not need the outer _id field which shown in the above result. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: no need to show extra information just show what you have and what you want that would be better instead of image. explanation can be like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612972/how-to-merge-two-array-of-object-by-using-lodash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first $unwind the issues sub array and using its result its possible to apply sort, skip and limit

Answer (score 4):

Your `sort` not working for field `issues.lastUpdatedTime` because `issues` is an array of object after `$lookup` just not a plain object. so you need to `$unwind` first then apply `sort`
After `sort` you should use `skip` and `limit`. like

```
{$unwind:"$issues"},
{$sort: {weight: -1, "issues.lastUpdatedTime": 1}},
{ $skip: 10 },// set value as you need 
{ $limit : 50 }// set value as you need
```

NB: `$limit` always should be after `$skip` for `aggregation`. so code will be like

```
db.organizations.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": { "from": "issues", "localField": "issues.str", "foreignField": "_id.str", "as": "issues" }
  },
  {$unwind:"$issues"},
  {$sort: {weight: -1, "issues.lastUpdatedTime": 1}},
  {$skip: 10},
  {$limit: 50}
]);
```

NB: If you want to return fixed amount of document after grouping then you should use `$skip` and `$limit` anfter `$group` stage

Comment: should be  working. what wrong data are you getting ?

Comment: Its not ordering the data wrt lastUpdatedTime and the whole records were showing after running this query. Skip and limit also not working. always showing the whole data

Comment: I want to order the items inside the _id shown on the attached image above and also I want to implement skip and limit for those data.

Comment: `skip` and `limit` applied for first level document not for nested documents

Comment: I want to get the nested array elements (issues) to outside and add skip and limits for those array elements. Is there any way for doing that?

Comment: could you please add example like what is your data and what is your expectation. that would be better to make solution @vijesh

Comment: @ Shaishab Roy I have updated my question with the  structure of data. please check