# Merge multiple array in lodash

Tags: node.js, lodash

> I want to merge these array in to single array with unique value.
>   don't want repeated values.

```
0:Array(2) ["General Fitness", "Health & Fitness"]
1:Array(2) ["Cardiovascular", "Meditation"]
2:Array(3) ["Health & Fitness", "Cardiovascular", "General Fitness"]
3:Array(1) ["Cardiovascular"]
```

> I am expecting this answer:

```
["General Fitness", "Health & Fitness", "Cardiovascular", "Meditation"]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two array of object by using lodash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38612972/how-to-merge-two-array-of-object-by-using-lodash)

Comment: _(data.hits.hits).map('_source.topics').compact().value() @ChrisR

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With lodash you can use [`_.union()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#union) and [`_.spread()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#spread) to generate a function that flattens to a single array with unique values:

```js
const fn = _.spread(_.union);

const arrs = [ 
  ["General Fitness", "Health & Fitness"],
  ["Cardiovascular", "Meditation"],
  ["Health & Fitness", "Cardiovascular", "General Fitness"],
  ["Cardiovascular"]
];

const result = fn(arrs);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Using ES6 you can [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the arrays, and make the result unique by passing it through a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), and [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) back to an array:

```js
const arrs = [ 
  ["General Fitness", "Health & Fitness"],
  ["Cardiovascular", "Meditation"],
  ["Health & Fitness", "Cardiovascular", "General Fitness"],
  ["Cardiovascular"]
];

const result = [...new Set(arrs.flat())];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 9):

```js
const arrs = [ 
  ["General Fitness", "Health & Fitness"],
  ["Cardiovascular", "Meditation"],
  ["Health & Fitness", "Cardiovascular", "General Fitness"],
  ["Cardiovascular"]
];

const result = _.uniq(_.flatten(arrs));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

use [union](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#union)

```js
var object =  ["General Fitness", "Health & Fitness"];
var other =  ["Cardiovascular", "Health & Fitness", "Meditation"]
 
_.union(object, other);

// ["General Fitness", "Health & Fitness", "Cardiovascular", "Meditation"]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use lodash [flatten method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-flatten-method/):

```
const arrs = [ 
  ["General Fitness", "Health & Fitness"],
  ["Cardiovascular", "Meditation"],
  ["Health & Fitness", "Cardiovascular", "General Fitness"],
  ["Cardiovascular"]
];

result = _.flatten(arrs);

console.log(result);
```