# lodash merge n number of arrays

Tags: javascript, lodash

i want to merge n number of arrays into one.

eg

```js
// Array1 

[{name:'abc', age:34},{name:'xyz', age:44},{name:'fng', age:54}]

// Array 2

[{name:'dgc', age:54}]

// Required output 

[{name:'abc', age:34},{name:'xyz', age:44},{name:'fng', age:54},{name:'dgc', age:54}]
```

i tried many other similar questions but nothing worked for me. please help me with example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge multiple array of object by ID in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505448/how-to-merge-multiple-array-of-object-by-id-in-javascript)

Comment: it didn't helped me

Comment: @Jay you have to do `_.concat(array1, array2, array3....)`

Answer (score 1):

Considering you want to merge `n` arrays, you can use an array with those arrays and use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)to merge them:

```js
var array1 = [{name:'abc', age:34},{name:'xyz', age:44},{name:'fng', age:54}];
var array2 = [{name:'dgc', age:54}];

var arrays = [array1, array2];

var merged = arrays.reduce((acc, next) => acc.concat(next));
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` and ES6 spread syntax.

```js
var arr1 = [{name:'abc', age:34},{name:'xyz', age:44},{name:'fng', age:54}]
var arr2 = [{name:'dgc', age:54}]

var r = [].concat(...arr1, ...arr2);
console.log(r)
```

Or you can create function that takes any number of arrays and return new array.

```js
var arr1 = [{name:'abc', age:34},{name:'xyz', age:44},{name:'fng', age:54}]
var arr2 = [{name:'dgc', age:54}]

let merge = (...arr) => [].concat(...arr);
console.log(merge(arr1, arr2))
```

Comment: i dont no of arrays ... it can be 3 or 5 or 100

Comment: just for example i gave 2

Comment: @Jay You can continue with `r = [].concat(...arr1, ...r);`