# React is mapping duplicate posts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React is mapping duplicate posts

like this

[image][image]

Ideally im just looking to map the likes array.

```
  {myLikes.map(like =>     

   )}
```

within the posts, i don't want duplicates posts. How would i achieve that ?

**PostList.js**

```
    render(){
        const {posts, myLikes} = this.props;
        return (    
        <div>
            {posts.map(post => (
                <div>
                {myLikes.map(like =>  
                <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>        
                        <PostItem  

                            myLikes={like}                 
                            myTitle={this.state.title} 
                            editChange={this.onChange} 
                            editForm={this.formEditing} 
                            isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id} 
                            removePost={this.removePost} 
                            {...post} 
                            // {...like}
                        />         

                </Paper>
                )}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isEditingId: state.post.isEditingId,
    myLikes: state.post.likes // reducer likes 
})
```

[image]

Posts

[image]

Likes

[image]

Comment: Remove duplicate values from the array before using `map()` , if you are using lodash, try `uniqBy()` to remove duplicate value.

Comment: is the problem that you have duplicate posts in array or that the react is rendering one post twice ?

Comment: react is rendering one post twice. Yes correct. in the console.log their 2 posts not 4. Its the map thats making it do it

Comment: what will be the correct way of doing it, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is due to nested maps in the PostList component, 
you can merge the mylikes and post arrays first and then use map

[How to merge multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505448/how-to-merge-multiple-array-of-object-by-id-in-javascript)

this is how it will work

```
const results = _.merge(myLikes, posts);
return (
  <div>
    {results.map(result => (
      <Paper key={result.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
        <PostItem
          myLikes={result.like}
          myTitle={this.state.title}
          editChange={this.onChange}
          editForm={this.formEditing}
          isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id}
          removePost={this.removePost}
        />
      </Paper>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: getting post is not defined.

Comment: `result.id` how do i know if not using the myLikes id, know what i mean ?

Comment: you can import _ from lodash

Comment: also how do i know if result.id is not using myLikes.id ?

Comment: can you send me the actual array i.e posts and myLikes, so i will update my answer again

Comment: can you share json for myLikes and posts separately, It is not yet completely visible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192449/discussion-between-tahir-iqbal-and-mr-patel).

Answer (score 4):

This is actually what you told React to do, without realizing it.

I'm assuming that `myLikes` is an array of numbers, in this case `[32, 15]`.

Your code says (in pseudocode form):

```
for each post p
    for each like l
        render the post p with like l
```

That gives you 2 * 2 = 4 copies.

Comment: thank you, what will be the right way to do it. without duplicate post items